custom build parameter in jenkins
Jenkins newbie here.
I have built a job in Jenkins with a parameterized build.  When I click on Build with Parameters, I have a dropdown menu of individual nodes to execute the job on.  I have 3 regions where groups of nodes in the list reside, my research is to have another dropdown list with the 3 regions that groups the nodes for each region.  The overall goal is to have all the nodes in each region execute the job at once, vs having to execute each node at a time.
I couldn't find a way to do this natively in Jenkins, is there any way to do this?  Thank you in advance.
Researched this ask on grouping, and customized parameters but couldn't find anything

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

This question is similar to: Running Jenkins job simultaneously on all nodes. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Jenkins does not work that way.
If you're looking for a tool that executes tasks on a number of servers, consider Ansible or other Infrastructure-as-Code/Configuration-as-Code automation tools. There you can define an inventory where your nodes could be grouped by region, and run the tasks against all of them, or any combination of them, at once or in rolling manner.
Jenkins runs the jobs on the build agents, and only selects one of the agents from the pool of currently available ones. Moreover, each agent (node) can have multiple executors to increase the capacity. Of course, one could write a pipeline that will do what you want, but it would be unnecessary overcomplicated and fragile. It's not the purpose of Jenkins.
